# Get all substrings inside string python

Tags: python, string

I need to get all substrings inside a given string:

At the moment I have this:

```
    def find_between(s, first, last):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

s = '<div class="figure"> <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_resource/4" title="vvv" alt="dovv" /><div class="figure"> <imgsrc="http://www.clickgratis.com.br/fotos-imagens/imagens/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW1nLm1pbmhhdGVjYS5jb20uYnIvMjliN2RhMDQwMjE0ZmU2NTI2MzBkZjQwMztitle="olaaaa" alt="oi" /><p class="caption">oi</p> </div>'

print find_between( s, '<img src="', '"')
```

However, it only gives the first substring found. How can I find all substrings?

Given a string containing HTML, I need to get the URLs from the `src` of the `img` tags, convert those images to base64, and then return a modified string with base64 versions of the images.

Here is my function to convert to base64:

```
def get64(url):
    a = base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content)
    return 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + a
```

This is the desired result:

```
 input: s = '<div class="figure"> <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_resource/4" title="vvv" alt="dovv" /><p
class="caption">dovv</p> </div> <p> <strong>ccdsfdsf</strong></p> <h3 id="fdsfdsfdsfdsfds">fdsfdsfdsfdsfds</h3>
<pre><code>fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds</code></pre> <pre class="sourceCode ruby"><code class="sourceCode ruby">require <span
class="st">&#39;redcarpet&#39;</span> markdown = <span class="dt">Redcarpet</span>.new(<span class="st">&quot;Hello
World!&quot;</span>) puts markdown.to_html</code></pre> <table> <thead> <tr class="header"> <th align="left">Tables</th> <th
align="center">Are</th> <th align="right">Cool</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr class="odd"> <td align="left">col 3 is</td> <td
align="center">right-aligned</td> <td align="right">$1600</td> </tr> <tr class="even"> <td align="left">col 2 is</td> <td
align="center">centered</td> <td align="right">$12</td> </tr> <tr class="odd"> <td align="left">zebra stripes</td> <td align="center">are
neat</td> <td align="right">$1</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <div class="figure"> <img
src="http://www.clickgratis.com.br/fotos-imagens/imagens/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW1nLm1pbmhhdGVjYS5jb20uYnIvMjliN2RhMDQwMjE0ZmU2NTI2MzBkZjQwMztitle="olaaaa" alt="oi" /><p class="caption">oi</p> </div>'

    output: s = '<div class="figure"> <img src="RETURNED_GET64" title="vvv" alt="dovv" /><p
class="caption">dovv</p> </div> <p><strong>ccdsfdsf</strong></p> <h3 id="fdsfdsfdsfdsfds">fdsfdsfdsfdsfds</h3>
<pre><code>fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds</code></pre> <pre class="sourceCode ruby"><code class="sourceCode ruby">require <span
class="st">&#39;redcarpet&#39;</span> markdown = <span class="dt">Redcarpet</span>.new(<span class="st">&quot;Hello
World!&quot;</span>) puts markdown.to_html</code></pre> <table> <thead> <tr class="header"> <th align="left">Tables</th> <th
align="center">Are</th> <th align="right">Cool</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr class="odd"> <td align="left">col 3 is</td> <td
align="center">right-aligned</td> <td align="right">$1600</td> </tr> <tr class="even"> <td align="left">col 2 is</td> <td
align="center">centered</td> <td align="right">$12</td> </tr> <tr class="odd"> <td align="left">zebra stripes</td> <td align="center">are
neat</td> <td align="right">$1</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <div class="figure"> <img
src="RETURNED_GET64" alt="oi" /><p class="caption">oi</p> </div>'
```

Comment: Please make an example with input and expected output. What if the substrngs overlap?

Comment: he wants to get the url of an image link

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis well the question title is much broader than that. We don't really know how general the solution has to be.

Comment: but if the task is to parse html, use a parser.

Comment: Hi, I Edited the question with desire

Comment: @timgeb I added more information

Comment: ok, use a html parser.

Comment: @timgeb it it the best solution to replace all urls ?

Comment: The string I send contain more that just images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to accomplish this, with `re.findall`.

```
import re

s = '<div class="figure"> <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_resource/4" title="vvv" alt="dovv" /><div class="figure"> <imgsrc="http://www.clickgratis.com.br/fotos-imagens/imagens/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW1nLm1pbmhhdGVjYS5jb20uYnIvMjliN2RhMDQwMjE0ZmU2NTI2MzBkZjQwMztitle="olaaaa" alt="oi" /><p class="caption">oi</p> </div>'

print re.findall("<img src=\"(.*?)\"", s)
```

`re.findall` will return a list of all matches of text between `<img src=\"` and `\"` (the parentheses around `.*?` match only the text between it, and not the image tag itself.)

Using the `s` from your example input:

```
>>> re.findall("<img src=\"(.*?)\"", s)
['http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_resource/4', 'http://www.clickgratis.com.br/fotos-imagens/imagens/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW1nLm1pbmhhdGVjYS5jb20uYnIvMjliN2RhMDQwMjE0ZmU2NTI2MzBkZjQwMztitle=']
```

To use this to replace the string with base64 images, you can use `re.sub`:

```
for image in re.findall("<img src=\"(.*?)\"", s):
    s = re.sub(image, get64(image), s)
```

This will replace all the images in `s` with their base64 version (as generated by your function).

So the full code would look like this:

```
import re, requests

s = '<div class="figure"> <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_resource/4" title="vvv" alt="dovv" /><div class="figure"> <imgsrc="http://www.clickgratis.com.br/fotos-imagens/imagens/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW1nLm1pbmhhdGVjYS5jb20uYnIvMjliN2RhMDQwMjE0ZmU2NTI2MzBkZjQwMztitle="olaaaa" alt="oi" /><p class="caption">oi</p> </div>'

print re.findall("<img src=\"(.*?)\"", s)

def get64(url):
    a = base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content)
    return 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + a

for image in re.findall("<img src=\"(.*?)\"", s):
    s = re.sub(image, get64(image), s)
```

Comment: It finds all, but how can I replace with another value?

Comment: @crazy_security Sorry about that, I didn't see your edit. I've edited my answer.

Comment: where is stored the new string ?

Comment: @crazy_security I just checked my code and there was a small error. If you use the new code, the string will be stored in `s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a toggling flag that turns on and off when a (") is found in the string:

```
s = '<div class="figure"> <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_resource/4" title="vvv" alt="dovv" /><div class="figure"> <imgsrc="http://www.clickgratis.com.br/fotos-imagens/imagens/aHR0cHM6Ly9zaW1nLm1pbmhhdGVjYS5jb20uYnIvMjliN2RhMDQwMjE0ZmU2NTI2MzBkZjQwMztitle="olaaaa" alt="oi" /><p class="caption">oi</p> </div>'

begin_string = False
list_of_sub_strings = []
sub_string = ""

for letter  in s:
    if letter == "\"":
        begin_string = not begin_string
        if not begin_string:
            list_of_sub_strings.append(sub_string)
            sub_string = ""

    if begin_string:
        sub_string += letter
```

So as you can see, every time a quotation mark is found, the substring starts reading letters, and when another quotation mark is found, the substring ends. And again if a third quotation mark is found, the second substring starts reading letters and so on.

So now you can use only the substrings that are URLs, by using an if statement in the for loop that appends only the desired sub strings to your list of sub strings.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is the `BeautifulSoup` library. It looks like you're using Python2, so you should be able to install with `python2 -m pip install beautifulsoup` and get started immediately.

My quick hack of a solution looks like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with open('whaver_filename.html') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())

for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    # using your function from above
    img['src'] = get64(img['src'])

with open('whatever_filename.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

The `BeautifulSoup` library home page is [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). If you install it the way I suggested above, you'll have version 3, which has more documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)